# Expect.toBeEqual is failing when an attribute is a function

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, vitest, testing-library, jest-dom

I have a simple test using `vitest` that is comparing a simple array with single item with same array. Here is the code.

```
import '@testing-library/jest-dom'
import { describe, it, expect } from 'vitest';

describe('Simple Test', () => {
  it('Test simple assertion', () => {
    expect([
      {
        id: "key1",
        header: "key1",
        cell: (e) => e["key1"],  <== This is the problematic line
      },
    ]).toEqual([
      {
        id: "key1",
        header: "key1",
        cell: (e) => e["key1"],  <== This is the problematic line
      },
    ]);
  });
});
```

The issue I'm facing is that assertion is failing with following error. If I comment out the above cell attribute in each of the array, the assertion is succeeding.

```
AssertionError: expected [ Array(1) ] to deeply equal [ Array(1) ]
    at /Volumes/Code/Nexus-BCM/src/Nexus-UCM/test/react/widgets/ListWidget.test.tsx:53:8
```

Can anyone suggest how I can make this assertion succeed?